# Notification when new record is added in database php-jquery

Tags: php, jquery, notifications

I need advice about the title above. I have the following piece of code :

**PHP :**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM i_case";
$qry = pg_query($connection, $sql);
$res = pg_num_rows($qry);   

$sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM i_case";
$qry_1 = pg_query($connection, $sql_1);
$res_1 = pg_num_rows($qry_1);

do {
    echo "new record on i_case";
} while($res !=  $res_1 and !(usleep(10000)));
```

**JQUERY :**

```
setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "file.php",
        success : function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
},1000);
```

It's not work that I expecting.

I don't know where is the matter from the code?

Comment: what exception? i dont understand?

Comment: response is -> new record on i_case

Comment: but there is no new record on table... no error! i put `error: function(){ alert("ERROR"); }`

Comment: if xdazz answered worked for you, then accept his answer..

Answer (score 6):

Your loop even won't run once because `$res` is same with `$res_1` in almost all cases. If the loop runs, it's a horrible infinite loop.

What you should do is like below.

***The javascript:***

```
var old_count = 0;

setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "file.php",
        success : function(data){
            if (data > old_count) {
                alert('new record on i_case');
                old_count = data;
            }
        }
    });
},1000);
```

***And the PHP code:***

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM i_case";
$qry = pg_query($connection, $sql);
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['count'];
```

Comment: but, when i refresh the page, last notification is shown again and again, any advice?

Comment: @jin you can load the initial record count first not just set to 0.

Answer (score 5):

A little tweak to xdazz answer. To avoid alert for first time when you load the page.

JS Code:

```
var old_count = 0;
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){    
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "notify.php",
    success : function(data){
        if (data > old_count) { if (i == 0){old_count = data;} 
            else{
            alert('New Enquiry!');
            old_count = data;}
        } i=1;
    }
});
},1000);
```

PHP Code:

```
include("config.php");   
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM Enquiry";
$qry = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['count'];
```

P.S. My first Stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Can you explain the the code                                                                               
    { if (i == 0){old_count = data;} 
     else{
    alert('New Enquiry!');
    old_count = data;}
    } i=1;

Answer (score 2):

I think your whole approach will not work. I suggest, PHP to only generate the count and JS to check if it has changed.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM i_case";
$qry = pg_query($connection, $sql);
$res = pg_num_rows($qry);   
echo $res;
```

and in JS, you could do somesthing like this:

```
var count_cases = -1;
setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "file.php",
        success : function(response){
            if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response) alert('new record on i_case');
            count_cases = response;
        }
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: so it call count_cases from -1, what if cases count already 50 record?

Comment: `-1` is just an init value, to prevent the `alert` in the first run of the function. After the 1st run, `count_cases` is initiated with -let's say- 50 and the function will trigger the alert, as soon as the PHP returns a number != 50 (likely > 50?)

Comment: btw: A full `SELECT` to just count the rows is very inefficient. Have a look on the `COUNT` statement in xdazz's answer

Comment: okay, i've tried to add new record, but notification is not appearing... why?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the you're connected to db?

i mean `$connection` variable returns true?, because i didn't found any code in php that connects to database.

If you could tell the what response you're getting from the server end, then i can help you bit more.